# Inherit view and adding fields

Tags: python, xml, odoo

[image]I want to add my 2 fields boatlenght and fuelcapacity under price list in product form view but they are not showing up. What did i miss.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <openerp>
        <data>
            <!-- Inherit Form View to Modify it -->
            <record id="product_product_template_only_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="model">product.product</field>
                <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <field name="list_price" position="after">
                       <field name="boatlenght"/>
                       <field name="fuelcapacity"/>
                </field>
                </field>
            </record>


        </data>
    </openerp>

  from openerp import models, fields, api

  class ProductProduct(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    boatlenght = fields.Char(string="Lenght of the Boat", required=False, )
    fuelcapacity = fields.Char(string="Fuel Capacity", required=False, )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<record id="product_product_template_only_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="model">product.product</field>
                <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <xpath expr="//field[@name='list_price']" position="after">
                       <field name="boatlenght"/>
                       <field name="fuelcapacity"/>
                    </xpath>
                </field>
            </record>
```

In order to [insert](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/views.html#inheritance) the field properly you use an xpath expression to insert it on the DOM.

Check the documentation.

Comment: Do you get an error? Have you inserted this xml file on your `__openerp__.py` file

Comment: yes its  in __openerp__.py. and no there is no errors actually if i find my APP and go to technical data it's says " Created Views
* INHERIT product.product form (form)" so im kinda confused here.