# Call Product Custom Field in Quotation Form in Odoo

Tags: odoo

i am using Odoo 10. I have successfully added a custom field in product mode. Field title is list and type is integer. Now I want to show this custom field in quotation where it should auto populate on selecting a product.

how I can achieve this?

field ===> x_product_list
model ===> product.template

Your help is appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, make sure that you add a custom field in the
  **sale.order.line** model *(For to be auto populated)*.
- Then using **xpath** add this field inside your one2many field of
  quotation **form view**.
- If you are using odoo v8 you can write **onchange** function depending on
  the product_id field, which will execute on selecting a product.
- Or you can directly override the function which is executed on selecting product (I guess 
  it's *on_change_prouct_id* (from XML)) and auto populate your new
  field

Comment: what do you mean by xpath here?

Comment: xpath is the way by which you add a new field to your quotation view. For reference http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/xpath-expressions-in-odoo-8/

Comment: Thank you. I have successfully added a custom file in product.template model. Now I want to show same field in quotation form. And when user selects a product this field should get the data from the product.template. I am stuck here. :( please assist me.

Comment: Add the same type of field in sale.order.line model and add this field inside the view of quotation using XPath

Comment: Thanks. My last question is where to add the 
`class on_change_function(models.Model):` function?

Comment: Inherit the sale.order.line model in your new class, and add the onchange function, which is depending on the product change

Comment: Should I need to write this in the same form view file?
Debug > Edit Form View > here ?

Comment: Already one onchange function is defined by odoo from XML. What you can do is, you can override this function. Otherwise, you can add @api.onchange('product_id') function in your new class where you will be overriding sale.order.line model

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the new field to the model that you want to show it on?

If so, then it is just a case of adding the new field to the required view.

If the field is on another model, then you may have to create a related field on the model where you want it to show it.

Are you saying it auto populates, or that you want it to auto populate?

As a guess, it sounds like you want something to appear when you select a product. This can be done via a computed field, or you may be able to achieve something by using an onchange event.

Comment: Thank you. Yes you are right. I have added a xyz field in product model. Now i want to show that field on quotation form view. how I can do it?

Comment: Auto populate means when a product is selected the custom filed should get value itself.

Comment: you inherit the view and make a modification. something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248731/inherit-view-and-adding-fields